# htmlspecialchars wont fix char error in xml, in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Somehow, in a customer's product theres a dot, `.` that shows a unknown char square, (i cant copy it to here), but you know those you see when you dont support a language on the web, happens at chinese sites often.

Those squares makes my whole xml file return error:

```
invalid character in attribute value
```

How can I, that do not have control to delete this character, to strip/convert this char and continue?

I did:

```
htmlspecialchars($description, ENT_COMPAT);
```

(description takes the description="" attribute, that this character is in.)

htmlspecialchars() helps me with alot of chars. But not this one. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `htmlspecialchars()`, try it with [`htmlentities()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which will attempt to encode any entity it can.

```
htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT|ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Okay now i receive "Entity 'aring' not defined" Which is the danish characters ÆØÅ it does not support. (Although it should since utf8 support æøå)

Comment: @Karem Does `ISO8859-15` help?

Comment: No just tried, same errors but just other names, example: 'Atilde' not defined

Comment: On http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlentities.php if you search after "aelig" (which is æ) then people uses arrays and some made functions. But how can i implement/use this?